# "naturally occurring substance"

Tags: verbs, adjectives

**Sentence**:

> Petroleum is defined as a gaseous, liquid, and semisolid naturally
>   occurring substance.

**Question**:

Here, **occurring** is used like an adjective, but it can only be used as a verb according to the dictionary. Why?

Comment: "Used as a verb" is probably where you are having trouble. Verb is a part of speech. How a part of speech functions is a different matter entirely. Verbs can be a part of many constructions with different functions. *Naturally occurring* is a multi-word adjective consisting of an adverb and a participle. It's interesting that this participle can't be used as an adjective by itself.

Comment: see here [attributive verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attributive_verb)

Comment: Hello, Liu. We're very wary about statements that are 'according to the dictionary'. The reference work needs to be stated. **Which** dictionary? (It's often found that other dictionaries disagree.) And when it comes to parts of speech, for the more difficult cases, dictionaries are notoriously unreliable – a grammar needs to be consulted (and often, different grammars don't agree).

Comment: Thank you all. Thanks for your remind!

Comment: Transformations in English: this substance occurs naturally=a naturally-occurring substance. That plant grows fast=a fast-growing plant. That man drinks hard=a hard-drinking man. And: a stupid-sounding comment=A comment that sounds stupid. A woman who sounds silly: a silly-sounding woman. These are basically "isomorphic" structures. I could do a longer analysis about when this is possible but I'm lazy. :) So, I am a lazy-sounding poster.